# Фреймворк Materialize CSS. Как скрыть мобильное меню по нажатию на кнопку?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, вёрстка, materialize-css

Здравствуйте! Использую для верстки сайта фреймворк [materialize](http://materializecss.com/side-nav.html#!user), возник вопрос следующего характера: возможно я чего-то не понимаю, но в нем не предусмотрена возможность закрытия моб.меню по нажатию на кнопку. Зато есть опция закрытия при нажатии на любую ссылку.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне заставить моб.меню скрываться по клику на кнопку таким образом, чтобы это происходило аналогично тому, как это сейчас происходит при нажатии на серую область при открытом меню? Линк на [кодпен](http://codepen.io/Vlastelin/pen/KNVPrj), если что.

```js
  $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
```

```css
.side-nav .btn-close {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/css/materialize.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-iconic-font/2.2.0/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


<ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav">
    <li><a class="btn-close" href="#close"><i class="zmdi zmdi-close-circle"></i></a></li>
    <li>
      <div class="userView">
        <div class="background">
          <img src="http://materializecss.com/images/office.jpg">
        </div>
        <a href="#!user"><img class="circle" src="http://materializecss.com/images/yuna.jpg"></a>
        <a href="#!name"><span class="white-text name">John Doe</span></a>
        <a href="#!email"><span class="white-text email">jdandturk@gmail.com</span></a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">cloud</i>First Link With Icon</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">Second Link</a></li>
    <li><div class="divider"></div></li>
    <li><a class="subheader">Subheader</a></li>
    <li><a class="waves-effect" href="#!">Third Link With Waves</a></li>
</ul>
<a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение вопроса, как оказалось, лежит на поврехности. У фреймворка Materialize возможность закрытия меню по нажатию на кнопку присутствует и описывается в [документации](http://materializecss.com/side-nav.html).

```js
$(".button-collapse").sideNav();

$(".btn-close").click(function() {
    $('#slide-out').sideNav('hide');
});
```

```css
.side-nav .btn-close {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/css/materialize.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-iconic-font/2.2.0/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


<ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav">
    <li><a class="btn-close" href="#close"><i class="zmdi zmdi-close-circle"></i></a></li>
    <li>
      <div class="userView">
        <div class="background">
          <img src="http://materializecss.com/images/office.jpg">
        </div>
        <a href="#!user"><img class="circle" src="http://materializecss.com/images/yuna.jpg"></a>
        <a href="#!name"><span class="white-text name">John Doe</span></a>
        <a href="#!email"><span class="white-text email">jdandturk@gmail.com</span></a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">cloud</i>First Link With Icon</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">Second Link</a></li>
    <li><div class="divider"></div></li>
    <li><a class="subheader">Subheader</a></li>
    <li><a class="waves-effect" href="#!">Third Link With Waves</a></li>
</ul>
<a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('.btn-close').click(function(){
  $('#slide-out').css('transform','translateX(-100%)')
})
```

Как то так...

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ. Такой вариант мною уже был испробован и должен сказать что результат оставляет желать лучшего.. Серый фон остается, моб.меню при повторном раскрытии, ведет себя некорректно, нужно другое решение..